# Weird git branch name

Tags: git, git-branch

I was trying to run the following command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=staging
```

And the result was not what i was expected. Instead of setting the upstream branch it created a new branch called `--set-upstream-to=staging` and the problem is that i cannot remove it.

Is there any way to make the

```
git branch -d --set-upstream-to=staging
```

command run successfully?

The error I get when I try to run the above command is:
    error: unknown switch `s'

[image]

I can confirm the existence of the branch when i run `git branch`

- ft-cell_formatting
  master
  staging
  —-set-upstream-to=staging
  —set-upstream-to=staging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of blue112 should work perfectly fine. However, if you find, that nothing else works, you can go plumbing. Look at the `.git/refs/heads` folder. It should look something like this:

```
$ ls .git/refs/heads
master
other-branch
--set-upstream-to=staging
```

Delete the file `.git/refs/heads/--set-upstream-to=staging`. Then the branch is gone. If you had commits there, they are now [dangling](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery), so you need to recover them manually. If not, you are done now.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you have weird filename / branchname / anythingname, you can make the command line not try to parse using:

```
 git branch -d -- --set-upstream-to=staging
```

The "--" is here to inform getopt (the module that is parsing the options) to stop parsing options and start parsing arguments.

---

By the way, there's no way git let me create a branch starting with a dash. I'm not sure how you did that.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. However, it doesn't let me remove it.

`error: branch '-set-upstream-to=staging' not found.`

Comment: Are you sure it actually exists ? Can you edit your question to include `git branch` output ?

Comment: @ppoliani in your commend you're only using one `-`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I can confirm, that my git v1.8.5 allows removal of a branch `--foo` with the command `git branch -d -- --foo`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an initialized branch in your local system and wanna push it to the  remote git repository you can:

`cd git_working_directory
git branch --set-upstream your_branch origin/your_branch
git push`

after that commands are executed your local branch will be pushed into remote repository and make a new branch